# Nested LinearLayout shows only the first View

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have seen some question the can be similar to this. However, those scenario were different and some are not for beginners.
So I just started Android recently. Please understand that I'm new to `*.xml`. Anyway, my concern is regarding the nested `LinearLayout` that only shows the first `View`.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/app_title">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_ok"
            android:onClick="changeMessage">
        </Button>

        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/this_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sample_text">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the XML so far. With this code, only the first TextView is only showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:layout_height="match_parent"` the height of the nested `LinearLayout` should be `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I'll try this after rebooting my PC.

Comment: Anyway, this is not an assignment. For the sake of my learning, if I may ask, what happened after setting the layout_height to match_parent? I do Java, so I was thinking that ViewGroup functions just like a JPanel.

Comment: with match_parent the view (the LineraLayout) will be high as its parent. With wrap_content it will be high as its content

Comment: Does that conclude that ViewGroup are not transparent by nature?

Comment: I think it depends on the theme. With the default theme the background is white. But, in your case that's not important. The Vertical LinearLayout works as a stack of layout, you put all the child one under the others. So if a child keeps all the space available there are no space for other child

Answer (score 1):

because you have given first `LinearLayout` width and height to `matchparent`

Change its height to `wrapcontent`

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_title">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>

// other layouts
```

Answer (score 1):

change the layout as below

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_title">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_ok"
        android:onClick="changeMessage">
    </Button>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/this_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sample_text">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Your inner Layouts are matching with the Parent layout so only first layout will be shown.